# Alert if the number is dividable by 3 or 5

Tags: javascript, function, modulus

I am trying to build a program that alerts to the user if the number that they've entered is dividable by 3 or 5. There is something wrong with my code apparently.
Here is is:

```
<p>Molimo unesite broj:</p> 
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="submit" onclick="check()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        var number = document.getElementsById('number').value;
        if (number % 3 === 0 || number  % 5 === 0) {
            alert("Broj je deljiv sa 3 ili sa 5");
        } else {
            alert("Broj nije deljiv sa 3 ili sa 5");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Fizz buzz, fizz buzz, lovely lovely fizz buzz.

Comment: My mistake. I should have check the code better before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Missed one curly bracket `}` ending the function
- It's `document.getElementById()`, not `document.getElementsById()` (`id` is unique - binded to one, single element)

```js
function check() {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  if (number % 3 === 0 || number % 5 === 0) {
    alert("Broj je deljiv sa 3 ili sa 5");
  } else {
    alert("Broj nije deljiv sa 3 ili sa 5");
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Molimo unesite broj:</p>
<input type="text" id="number" />
<input type="submit" onclick="check()" />
```